# Transfer ownership of a file fails - even as Super Administrator (Google Drive API, Java)

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to transfer ownership of files to Super Administrator. The essential part of the code is shown below. The same code works if I transfer ownership of a document that I own. But in this case the original owner is another user in the same domain. [EDIT] *I know there is a "transfer-ownership-of-files-from-1-user-to-another" in admin panel, but this is needed for a case when multiple files/folders, from multiple owners needs to be transferred programmatically.* [/EDIT]

So the simple scenario is:

1. **user@domain.com** owns a file
2. the ownership needs to be transferred to the **admin@domain.com** (Super Administrator). The code is running in AppEngine in Java Servlet. And the Super Administrator is authenticated with OAuth.

However it throws (500 OK) exception always in line `update.execute();` (showed in the end).
Is this operation impossible even for a Super Admin?

Thanks for any tips!

```
try {
   Drive service = getDriveService();
   Permission newPerm = new Permission();
   newPerm.setValue("admin@domain.com");
   newPerm.setType("user");
   newPerm.setRole("writer");
   newPerm = service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPerm).execute();
   newPerm.setRole("owner");
   Update update = service.permissions().update(fileId, newPerm.getId(), newPerm);
   update.setTransferOwnership(true);
   update.execute(); 
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   log.severe(e.getMessage());
}
```

The exception thrown looks like:

```
SEVERE: 500 OK
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal Error",
    "reason" : "internalError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal Error"
}
```

Comment: Someone (a Google engineer) has changed the tag of your question but I'm afraid this tag is not appropriate... not sure you'll get the best return around here.

Comment: My original tag was google-app-engine, is this google-drive-sdk correct now?

Comment: I am still confused about this. Is it about now having rights or is the 'workflow' incorrect: adding "write" permission and then changing it to "owner"? I'd expect unauthorized error if this is not allowed not 500 OK, which does not tell much. 

Also I can see that com.google.api.services.drive.model.File has setOwners(List<User>) I tried also that but it didn't work either. I called service.update(fileId, file).execute(); after changing the owner-list, but it had no effect...

Comment: have "getDriveService" take a parameter, an email address of the current owner. Then call "setServiceAccountUser" when getting the drive service, and thus impersonating the current owner.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working at least partly. Thanks @ZigMandel for the "impersonation" hint! Now I followed this [Domain-wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation) carefully. And used the `GoogleCredential` created using "Service account"-key. With this credential I can impersonate the Drive API operations like adding permissions and transferring ownership to Admin, for example.

The problem that still remains is that with current Drive API it is impossible to programmatically determine the owner email address, which is needed for impersonated credential creation. Now I need to find a workaround for this. Anyway the fundamental idea works now. Thanks!

Comment: I got it working to. All I had to do was call setServiceAccountUser("email address of the current owner") GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
            .setServiceAccountUser("other-user@domain.com")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
            .build();

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to do it from apps script.
Can be done from appengine. Ive done it but its beyond of the scope to explain here. Involves using the drive api on behalf of the file owner and adding the oauth permissions at the domain level.

Comment: Hi, I tagged this originally as google-app-engine and someone changed it to "scripts", now it seems to be google-drive-sdk, which is correct I guess!? Anyway I forgot originally to emphasize that this is indeed done in AppEngine with Drive Java SDK (not in Google Scripts). Also the Super Admin is authenticated with OAuth here. Unfortunately the exception does not reveal what goes wrong here if it should work. Does anyone have some advice how to troubleshoot this? Thanks!

Comment: See the drive api docs on user impersonation. There are examples for it.

Comment: Thanks Zig! Today after some searching I ended up here https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts I managed to create a service key and build GoogleCredential in my AppEngine code. But now I can not access even the files/permissions data. Files are not found with the correct file ID. Sorry I am quite new with these so maybe I got lost in wrong examples? Do you happen to have some pointer to an example where similar operations are done i.e. moving ownership from a user to domain admin (programmatically). Thanks again for any tips!