# Delete file in v3 with Python [Service Account]

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I'm using Google Drive, and my code's using v3 for work with files by Service Account.
I can read, download the file, but I can't delete.
I tried with v2 delete (I don't find v3 delete) and no works(not permissions). I tried after with V2 impersonate admin account and no works.

Recently, I tried with [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests) but, no works for no scopes

```
def get_credenciales_with_impersonate():    
    delegated_credentials =  get_credenciales().create_delegated(admin_email)
    from httplib2 import Http
    http_auth = get_credenciales().authorize(Http())
    print(type(http_auth))
   return http_auth
```

...

```
serviceV2Impersonate = discovery.build('drive','v2',http=get_credenciales_with_impersonate())
```

My normal credentials is:

```
def get_credenciales():
    credenciales = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    client_email,p12_file)
    return credenciales
```

and works

```
serviceV2 = discovery.build('drive','v2',credentials=credentials)
serviceV3 = discovery.build('drive','v3',credentials=credentials)
```

How I could delete a file from drive with v3 and Python?

- Service account with XXXXX@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
- The other email is admin email
- The owner of the file is admin email. I can´t change the owner -differents domains between gserviceaccount and my domain-
- Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

There's [Files: delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/delete#request) for Google Drive Rest API V3 using HTTP request format:

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId
```

However, please not that this is only possible if you use the owner's email which is the admin email.

> Permanently deletes a file owned by the user without moving it to the trash. If the target is a folder, all descendants owned by the user are also deleted.

And since we can not transfer file ownership due to different domain issues, kindly try the given solution in this SO post - [How to delete a google docs without ownership using an API/Services account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039210/how-to-delete-a-google-docs-without-ownership-using-an-api-services-account/31062177#31062177). I hope it works.

Comment: from the link, Python has SignedJwtAssertionCredentials . Google change this with http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html: `def get_credenciales_with_impersonate():
 f = file(p12_file,'rb')
 key = f.read()
 f.close()
 credenciales = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
     client_email,p12_file,scopes=SCOPES)
 return credenciales.create_delegated(admin_email)`  and  `serviceV3Impersonate =discovery.build('drive','v3',http=get_credenciales_with_impersonate())`

 not works (ServiceAccountCrededntials object has no attribute request)

Answer (score 0):

In v3, you have to call `files.update` with `{'trashed':true}`.

If you want to find a v3 function that you know exists, check [Migrate to Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#methods).

Comment: I tried: `def borrarDeDrive(service,item):
 try:
  file_metadata = {
   'trashed' : True
  }
  service.files().update(fileId = item['id'],
        body = file_metadata).execute();
 except errors.HttpError, error:
  print("No se pudo borrar el archivo: %s" % error)` 
and I got <HttpError 403 when requesting ******** returned "The user
does not have sufficient permissions for this file."> (this i published in the initital post).

Comment: Try to go to your google domain admin panel and under security settings -> Advanced Settings -> Manage API client access

Add your client ID and the scope in there

Comment: I added client ID and the scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'. I run the app and i have same error ("The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file")

Answer (score 0):

Example using Python Drive API.
There is an assumption below that the service account has access to the file with `file_id`

```
from apiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service-account.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# delete file using file id
file_id='<your file id here>'
service.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()
```

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python