# How to write Google Sheets Script to automatically delete files not owned me

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, delete-file

I have a Sheets form that our company users save to our Company google Drive Folder (G Suite). We are required to keep these forms for 30 days.

I would like to automatically delete these files after 35 days. So I wrote this Script:

```
function DeleteOldFiles() {
  var Folders = new Array(
    '0B8xnkPYxGFbUMktOWm14TVA3Yjg',      
   '1C_VUaqPl9FQlaajY_wsZzJgVGHDrPKm8');
  var Files;

  Logger.clear();

  for each (var FolderID in Folders) {
    Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FolderID)
    Files = Folder.getFiles();

    while (Files.hasNext()) {
      var File = Files.next();

      if (new Date() - File.getLastUpdated() > 35 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
       File.setTrashed(true); // Places the file int the Trash folder
      //  Drive.Files.remove(File.getId()); // Permanently deletes the file
        Logger.log('File ' + File.getName() + ' was deleted.');
      }}}

  if(Logger.getLog() != '')
    MailApp.sendEmail('batnip@choiceaviation.com', 'Backups have been removed from Google Drive', Logger.getLog());}
```

The problem, is Im getting these messages sometimes:
    "Access denied: DriveApp. (line 18, file "Code")"

Sometimes the Script works, and other times it does not. I finally came to the conclusion that it probably works only when deleting my own files, but not when another G Suite user has a file on there.

Solution?

Comment: Have you tried looking at these threads: [23874766](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874766/), [82416](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82416/how-do-i-delete-a-shared-google-drive-document-owned-by-somebody-else)?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, [only the owner may validly use the .setTrashed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setTrashed(Boolean)) function. You could try setting yourself as the owner first, using [.setOwner(email address)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setOwner(String)):

```
if (new Date() - File.getLastUpdated() > 35 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) {
   File.setOwner('your email address'); // Transfers ownership to user
   File.setTrashed(true); // Places the file int the Trash folder
  //  Drive.Files.remove(File.getId()); // Permanently deletes the file
    Logger.log('File ' + File.getName() + ' was deleted.');
  }}}
```

If this doesn't work - it requires domain admin privileges, I believe - you could also try creating an archive folder as a workaround and simply moving the files into that, as outlined here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/38808875/moving-files-in-google-drive-using-google-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808875/moving-files-in-google-drive-using-google-script).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The 'File.setOwner' did not work. (Im not sure why as I am the Super Admin (Gsuite owner) for the company. Any idea on how to change this setting?

Answer (score 0):

The proper tool for the problem is a Google Shared Drive. But if that doen't work in your situation, you can make your own trash folder (e.g. 'ToTrash'). Then give to the people that can trash, permission to this folder. Instead of trashing you let people use a script that moves files to your own 'ToTrash' folder. Once in a while you delete all files in the 'ToTrash' folder. For that you can also write a script that is automatically triggered for example once every day.

```
/* TRASHFOLDERID is the Id of your own created trash folder.
/* assuming that file is a file object you constructed
/* by getting it by id, name, or FileIterator
const trashFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(TRASHFOLDERID);
file.moveTo(trashFolder);
```