# Does google have a mechanism (API support) to delete root files from multiple google drive account?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am  looking for some idea to delete files from root google drive folder of multiple accounts (1000+).  I am able to delete file under the shared folder, shared from my account across these 1000+ accounts using Google Drive API, but the issues is that some users tend to copy files from shared folder to their root. The  accounts are created by us, but don't  want to login and  clean up one at a time, rather  would like a code/script to clear/empty them and  make  these accounts reusable for other users within the  org. Is it possible using a google service account and  how?

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it is impossible to tell the difference between a file that is copied and one that is created. So you cannot actually determined if the file is the one that was originally copied.

If what you need is to "clean up" you could just delete the users and create them again. 
 1. [Delete User](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33314?hl=en&ref_topic=4388359)
 2. Create new user.

In case you delete something you shouldn't, here is how to [restore deleted user](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1397578?hl=en&ref_topic=4388359). Keep in mind this is only possible within 20 days of deletion.

If you still want to try you could [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) all the files from every user and try to [query parts of the name](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) with the relevant fields you could correlate with the original file. But take into consideration that for that you would need to enable [Domain-Wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#perform_g_suite_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority). Look at this answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874766/delete-a-file-from-different-owner-with-google-drive-api) if you want to take this path.